# C# Universal OleDb connection to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I have an ASP-MVC aplication that allows the user to Upload an Excel file. I'm supporting *.xls files (Excel 97-2003) and *.xlsx files (Excel 2007+).

Once the file is uploaded, the program opens an OleDB connection to the excel file using one of the available drivers:

- Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0  for newest Excel file formats.
- Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0  for older Excel file formats.

What I have at the moment of writing this post is an *if* block of code that checks the mime-type of the Excel file to be opened and chooses the correct driver for opening the OleDb connection. But I can't support both file formats at the same time.

If I execute my ASP app in **64bit-mode**, I get the error:

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

If I execute my ASP app in **32bit-mode**, I get the error:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

If there a universal Microsoft OleDb provider that is able to connect to all versions of Excel files?

**Update:** I'm running on a 64bit version of Windows Server 2008 SP1 with .NET Framework 4

Comment: try the 2007 32 bit version. I think it will work for you. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Comment: I hit the same problem some time ago. End up that the more compatible way is to just accept CSV instead.

Comment: Download and use the "*Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010*". However make sure you have uninstalled all the older versions such as 2007 before you install the latest version. Let me know if this helped.